# Disable div onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 4 divs that onClick call a function. When the particular div is clicked, I want the other divs to be non-clickable. But until the particular div is clicked, I want them to be clickable. My code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyApp extends Component {
    state = {
        div:2
    }

    handleClick = (id) => {
        id==this.state.div? 
        //disable onClick for all divs :
        //do nothing
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
            <div onClick={()=>this.handleClick(1)}>
                1
            </div>
            <div onClick={()=>this.handleClick(2)}>
                2
            </div>
            <div onClick={()=>this.handleClick(3)}>
                3
            </div>
            <div onClick={()=>this.handleClick(4)}>
                4
            </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
}


export default MyApp
```

How do I do this? Am I correct in disabling the click from the `handleClick` function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `locked` to your `state` and set it to true when you want to lock other `divs` and return from your function if its `true`

I would also change the `handleClick` function to return a new function to keep the code more readable

```
class MyApp extends Component {
  state = {
    div: 2,
    locked: false
  };

  handleClick = id => () => {
    if (this.state.locked) return;

    if (id === this.state.div) {
      this.setState({ locked: true });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div onClick={this.handleClick(1)}>1</div>
        <div onClick={this.handleClick(2)}>2</div>
        <div onClick={this.handleClick(3)}>3</div>
        <div onClick={this.handleClick(4)}>4</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If you don't want to register any handler you can also check if `this.state.locked` is true and return `null` to the `onClick` function

```
class MyApp extends Component {
  state = {
    div: 2,
    locked: false
  };

  handleClick = id => {
    if (this.state.locked) return null;

    return () => {
      if (id === this.state.div) {
        this.setState({ locked: true });
      }
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div onClick={this.handleClick(1)}>1</div>
        <div onClick={this.handleClick(2)}>2</div>
        <div onClick={this.handleClick(3)}>3</div>
        <div onClick={this.handleClick(4)}>4</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This works!! So if `if (this.state.locked) return;`  this condition is met, the function just stops there?

Comment: @Somename You're welcome, yes after we set locked state to true the function is basically not going to do anything

Comment: is `null` a valid value for an event listener when using jsx? I think it needs to be `undefined` or React will complain. But I could be wrong

Comment: @Andrew React won't complain if the `onClick` value is `null || undefined` but will complain for `false || 0`

Answer (score 1):

While this is more of a semantic argument, you are still firing an event in each div, regardless of its state. You're just deciding whether or not any action should be taken. If you want to make it truly have no behavior, then you have to dynamically add/remove them. The easiest way is to iterate and create the 4 divs, with a conditional to see if an `onClick` listener should be added

```
buildDivs() {
  return [1,2,3,4].map(id => {
    const divProps = {}
    if (this.state.div === id) {
      divProps.onClick = () => this.handleClick(id)
    }
    return <div {...divProps} key={id}>{id}</div>
  }
}
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.buildDivs}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: where is `key` ?

Answer (score 1):

This is another approach I made and I hope it makes sense and helps. let me know if you have any questions

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      buttonClick: 2,
      buttons: [1,2,3,4],
      clicked: false
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick(id){
    console.log('clicked ', id)
    this.setState({
      buttonClick: id,
      clicked: true
    })
  }

  renderInitButtons() {
     const {buttons} = this.state;
    return buttons.map(button => {
      return <div onClick={() => this.handleClick(button)}> {button} </div>
    })
  }
  renderButtonClicked() {
    const {buttons, buttonClick} = this.state;
    return buttons.map(button => {
      if(buttonClick === button) {
        return <div onClick={() => this.handleClick(button)}> {button} </div>
      }
      return <div > {button} </div>
    })
  }

  render() {
    const {buttons, buttonClick, clicked} = this.state;
    return (
    <div> 
    {
      clicked? this.renderButtonClicked(): this.renderInitButtons()
    }
    </div>
    )
  }
}
render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```